# Magento 2 module “data_version - not upgrading"?

Tags: magento2, setup-script

In Magento 2.0 I have written `UpgradeData` and `UpgradeSchema` and I have changed the `setup_version` in `module.xml`. After that I run **php bin/magento setup:upgrade** After this in the database, `schema_version` is upgrading but `data_version` not upgrading. Any Ideas?

`UpgradeData.php`

```
namespace Vendor\Pawan\Setup;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

/**
 * Upgrade data for SImple Google Shopping
 */
class UpgradeData implements UpgradeDataInterface
{

    /**
     * @param ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup
     * @param ModuleContextInterface   $context
     */
    public function upgrade(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {

        // $context->getVersion() = version du module actuelle
        // 10.0.0 = version en cours d'installation

        if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '10.0.0') < 0) {
            $installer = $setup;
            $installer->startSetup();
            // do what you have to do

            $installer->endSetup();
        }
    }
}
```

Module.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Vendor_Pawan" setup_version="2.1.1">

    </module>
</config>
```

Comment: can you post your code?

Comment: Module.xml :::: <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Vendor_Pawan" setup_version="2.1.1">

    </module>
</config>

Comment: the above is my code

Answer (score 0):

$setup->startSetup() and $setup->endSetup() should be outside if clause.

```
namespace Vendor\Pawan\Setup;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

/**
 * Upgrade data for SImple Google Shopping
 */
class UpgradeData implements UpgradeDataInterface
{

    /**
     * @param ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup
     * @param ModuleContextInterface   $context
     */
    public function upgrade(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {

        $setup->startSetup();
        // $context->getVersion() = version du module actuelle
        // 10.0.0 = version en cours d'installation

        if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '10.0.0') < 0) {
            // do what you have to do

        }
        $setup->endSetup();
    }
}
```